# How can i save Battery power using in writing app

Tags: android

In Android 4.4 kit-kat version I saw my writing app is using high battery power ... 
in my application I am using Network service to fetch data from server.
so I search the solution to save the battery power .. I found this topic

http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html#PrefetchData

Any others ways to save the Battery Power Useage and best pratice for reduce battery power using in application.

Comment: Simple: do less of whatever you are doing (CPU, graphics, timers, polling, network). However, I don't know what you are doing so its hard to be more specific.

Comment: i fetch data from web api and show in the google map view .... by lat and lng ... when running my application  OS show , my application is High battery use , i wanna to reduce power usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking steps such as disabling background service updates when you lose connectivity, or reducing the rate of such updates when the battery level is low, you can ensure that the impact of your app on battery life is minimized, without compromising the user experience.For more take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html). Check which part of your app is consuming the thread [profiling with trace View](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html).  And you also need to aware of your app [performance](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html).

Comment: Thank for Answer , i will try with this ways