# How to reduce the battery power consumption?

Tags: android, google-maps, battery-saver

In my application I'm using Google Maps and getting latlon from onLocationChanged(), while it's running in background and also getting that value using services.

Due to this, a lot of battery power is consumed by my application

How can I reduce my application power consuming?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278873/how-can-i-save-battery-power-using-in-writing-app

Comment: How do you implement the services? Do you use a `Timer` or `AlarmeManager`, or you just keep listening to `onLocationChanged`?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: Rewirte the app ... especially you should change line 666 in ThererIsNoCode.java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200818/get-location-coordinates-periodically-without-dramatically-increase-battery-co

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

Use `setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);` in `LocationRequest`

See documentation [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest):